# Why has PHP different (non-equal) versions of the logical operators (&& vs. and, || vs or)?

Tags: php, language-design, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I know the difference between `and` vs. `&&` and `or` vs. `||` in PHP, they have different priority while being parsed ([manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)).

My question is why do they exist, what is the historical reason, what was the intention of the language creators to introduce multiple but non-equal instances of the same mathematical operator?

Comment: Well, you know, PHP has always been a bit chaotic. So, don't ask for coherency in everything PHP related. Take a look: http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: Care to explain the -1? SO.com is quick in downvoting these days...

Comment: @FooBar they always are fast with downvotes. have my upvote ;)

Comment: @Amarnasan I know that PHP is often chaotic. But still the creators had to have something in mind when creating specific details of the language (they are not stupid, they created one of the most used languages, after all). So, what's wrong with trying to understand some decisions?

Comment: the downvote is probably due to the fact that SO is not meant for this type of questions.

Comment: @NDM Is there a better place for these questions? I always take a look at the available tags to decide. And this time the tag "language-design" seemed appropriate.

Comment: @PaulCrovella But other languages do not have two versions (some have both versions that behave identical, however). So, what was the reason for the PHP creators to decide to have differently behaving operators?

Comment: FooBar, I think you have the wrong impression that I downvoted your question, or that I despise it. And I didn't. On the other hand: There's nothing wrong trying to understand some decisions, but I think the main reason is : when you start something bad, you cannot fix it, just parch it.

Comment: Questions asking for what was in the mind of a developer when they made a particular decision are impossible to answer unless you actually are that developer.... otherwise they can only ever be speculation.... and given PHP, that can often lead to insulting responses

Comment: @Amarnasan Sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't address you, I send the comment at the same time (apparantly some milliseconds later) than you yours.

Comment: PHP was not designed, it grew organically. In the early versions the author(s) added features as they needed them. Read about the PHP [history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History) on Wikipedia. Rasmus Lerdorf (the creator) says: *"there was never any intent to write a programming language […] I have absolutely no idea how to write a programming language, I just kept adding the next logical step on the way"*. I guess the irresistible desire to use shortcuts like `$conn = mysql_connect(...) or die();` was the source of the `and` and `or` operators and their strange precedence.

Answer (score -1):

From comments on [precedence page](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#117390)

> Watch out for the difference of priority between 'and vs &&' or '|| vs or':

```
<?php
$bool = true && false;
var_dump($bool); // false, that's expected

$bool = true and false;
var_dump($bool); // true, ouch!
?>
```

> Because 'and/or' have lower priority than '=' but '||/&&' have higher.

Comment: That's just amazing. Kudos for PHP.

Comment: @Amarnasan Yeah, it's one of the many gotchas PHP has, but there was probably a reason at the time to add this. I make no defense of the wisdom of doing it this way

Comment: I know about all these odd behaviours. ;) I asked about the *why are they existing at all*.

Comment: PHP has copied this from Perl, but imho it is much more coherently integrated in the Perl syntax. and/or is mostly used for things like checking something and providing an alternative, like `$a = doSomething() or die('...');`, in contrary to &&/||, which is used to calculate the outcome of boolean values.

Comment: @syck Nice, didn't know Perl had this, too. I do know however that PHP originated from Perl. So we are getting closer to the answer. :)

Comment: The main difference is that &&/|| have a higher precedence than the assignment operator, while and/or's is lower (and therefore the outcome of the assigned expression is used), as machavity mentioned.